# Rails validating values in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, activerecord

In my Schedule model I want to add some validation to the :wdays field, which is an int[]. I only want values 0..6 to be valid

Valid

```
Schedule.wdays = [0,1,6]
```

Invalid

```
Schedule.wdays = [0,1,10]
```

I tried using

```
validates :wdays, inclusion: { in: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

and

```
validates :wdays, inclusion: { in: 0..6 }
```

but neither works

What is the proper way to validate the values in an array in your model?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think that default Rails validators will do the trick here, you can do this though:

```
validate :validate_wdays

def validate_wdays
  if !wdays.is_a?(Array) || wdays.any?{|d| !(0..6).include?(d)}
    errors.add(:wdays, :invalid)
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work fully... if someone sets `wdays = 'meow'` it'll set it to empty array `[]` without warning. Something above the stack is happening where it's already converting the data into an array if it's invalid

Answer (score 8):

I'm not certain whether there are easier ways to handle this within the existing Rails validation structure. You've got an odd case that the validators weren't really built to handle. You might need to write a custom validator for something like this (assuming an existing validation extension gem isn't available). Something like this:

```
class ArrayInRangeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, valueArray)
    valueArray.each do |value|
      record.errors.add "#{attribute} - #{value}", (options[:message] || "is not in the acceptable range") unless (1..6).include?(value)
    end
  end
end
```

and then in your model:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    validates :wdays, :presence => true, :array_in_range => true

    ... other model stuff
end
```

Comment: @tirdadc I added some of the updates from your edit, however can you verify that the name of the validator must be an underscored version (that it should be `array_in_range` rather than `arrayInRange`? Do you know of any documentation on that convention?

Comment: the name of the validator should be underscored

Answer (score 3):

I created this gem:
https://github.com/rafaelbiriba/active_model_validates_intersection_of

Basicaly, you can use like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   DEFAULT_PERMISSION = ["read", "write", "share"]
   validates_intersection_of :permission, in: DEFAULT_PERMISSION
end
```

and if you try:

```
user = User.new(permission: ["read", "share"])
user.valid? #true

user = User.new(permission: ["read", "admin"])
user.valid? #false
```

Enjoy! Comments, pull requests and feedbacks is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't really do this correctly in my opinion. If someone sets `wdays = 'meow'` it'll set it to empty array `wdays == []` without warning.

Type Casting is happening you ask for `wdays` in that method. It's already converting the data into an array if it's invalid.

`wdays_before_type_cast` should be used instead of `wdays` when checking type.

See [_before_type_cast](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html)

```
validate :validate_wdays

def validate_wdays
  errors.add(:wdays, :invalid) if wdays_changed? && !wdays_before_type_cast.is_a?(Array)
  errors.add(:wdays, :invalid) if wdays.any? { |d| (0..6).exclude?(d) }
end
```